# Using Bind attribute with a JSON input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a WebAPI method which accepts a parameter like this:

```
public async Task<string> GetAmountDetails ([FromBody] MessageFormat msgFormat)
{
   var amountDTO = JSON.DeserializeObject<CustomerAmount>(msgFormat.Parameters[param],JsonSerializeSettings);

}
```

Here, MessageFormat is a JSON format which contains parameters and other information. CustomerAmount is a model in a separate project.

We have a third-part code review tool which is showing security alert in this code. It suggests to use attribute:

`[Bind(Include="",...)]`.

I want to know how to use this Bind as we are getting parameters in JSON format.

Comment: If you are doing this property by using a view model, then a `[Bind]` attribute is never required (and your  _third-part code review tool_ is wrong)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am not using ViewModel. This is a WebAPI method in a class.

Comment: [Bind Is Evil](https://cpratt.co/bind-is-evil/)

Comment: Agree with Stephen, the third party tools you are using sucks and likely not compatible with ASP.NET Core. You use `[Bind]` when you have form data (posts from veiws) to bind it into a model (or exclude specific properties). FromBody is required for json payload. With ASP.NET Core  2.1 you can use `[ApiController]` on the Controller class to reduce the number of required attributes (i.e. `[FromBody]` attributes on webapi actions). Check this blog post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-web-apis/

Comment: The security tool is probably calling it "overposting" and demanding the model properties are each white-listed. I don't like that approach, I think it's best to validate everything on the model. Ref: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETOverpostingMassAssignmentModelBindingSecurity.aspx